# Google Vision API Base64 decoding failed

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have sent Base64 data to Google Vision API and it works on one of my web servers, but does not work on another web server.

I get the error:
Invalid value at 'requests[0].image.content' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for "... base64 data here ..."

I try a different image on both servers and it works on both web servers and Google Vision API returns good results.

The base64 data that i am sending from both webservers is identical.  The Programming i am using to send (ColdFusion) is identical.

I would paste the Base64 data here, but it is a lot of text...

Is there anything on the Google Vision API console that will give me information on my failures so i can compare them to the successes?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there's an issue with your base64 data. Maybe worth pasting it in https://pastebin.com/ or as a github gist. Note that there's different types of base64 encoding (see variants in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table), so as a theory you library versions could differ resulting in a different default parameter being used?